# jquery form submit with dynamic id not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't submit the form with dynamic id. Below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fval;    
var cvalue = "<?php echo $_POST['currentval']; ?>";
if(!(cvalue)) cvalue=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#upload'+cvalue).submit(function() {
    var options = {
        target: '#message', 
        url:'process.php?sval='+cvalue, 
        success:  function() {
        alert("success");
        $('#uploader').html('');

        }
    };
$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
return false;
});
});
</script>
<div id="message"></div>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    echo "<form action='#' method='post'  name='upload' id='upload$i' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";   
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='svalhid'  id='svalhid' value='$i'>";
    echo "<input type='file' id='fl$i' name='filename".$i."up'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='currentval' id='currentval' value='$i'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='uploads$i' value='Ok'><br>";
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

In this line, `$('#upload'+cvalue).submit(function() {`

I can't get the cvalue. I can't identify what's wrong with this code. Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check follow line

```
echo "<form action='#' method='post'  name='upload' id='upload$i' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
```

Are you really sure that you printed out a correct value for the id attribute?

I think it exists two better ways:

1st (the best way in my eyes):

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
?>
    <form action='#' method='post'  name='upload' id='upload<?php echo $i ?>' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";   
    <input type='hidden' name='svalhid'  id='svalhid' value='<?php echo $i ?>'>"
    <input type='file' id='fl<?php echo $i ?>' name='filename<?php echo $i ?>up'>";
    <input type='hidden' name='currentval' id='currentval' value='<?php echo$i ?>'>"
    <input type='submit' name='uploads<?php echo $i ?>' value='Ok'><br>"
    </form>'
<?php
}
?>
```

2nd: Change the mentioned line to following:

```
echo "<form action='#' method='post'  name='upload".$i."' id='upload".$i."' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
```

Note: You defined a couple of forms with the same name. As far as I know, the attribute 'name' is the main attribute for forms, not the 'id' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you assign anything besides "" or 0 to cvalue. Also, those two assignments are outside of $(document).ready(function() { so there could be something weird going on with that code executing before your document has fully loaded. Move them inside of the document.ready call and see what happens.

Comment: Also, try this to see if your element actually exists:
    if ($(selector).length>0) {
        alert('element exists');
    }

Comment: I put the two lines var cvalue = "<?php echo $_POST['currentval']; ?>"; and
 if ($('#upload'+cvalue).length>0) { alert('element exists'); } inside $(document).ready(function() { then "element exists" is alerted

Comment: Cool, glad it's working. Go ahead and mark one of the responses on this page as the answer...

Comment: But this line $('#upload'+cvalue).submit(function() {  and the code below this line is not working

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to check process.php?sval=123 in your browser and verify that it's actually sending a response back, triggering your success function.

Comment: Atlast I found the answer. The line $('#upload'+cvalue).submit(function() {  should be replaced as  $('form:upload'+cvalue).submit(function() { then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var cvalue = "<?php echo $_GET['currentval']; ?>";
```

or

```
var cvalue = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['currentval']; ?>";
```

Also try what @reporter said about the form id: id='upload".$i."
The form id should be the same as the one referenced here:

```
$('#upload'+cvalue).submit(function() {
```

Example:

in javascript:

```
$('#upload').submit(function() {
```

then form should be:

```
<form id="#upload" ...
```

You should definitely see something happen. 
Try installing firebug and use console.log(variablehere) instead of alert(variablehere). It's more cleaner.

Hope that helps